# WHERE b.maxOrdini > maxordine throws "The identification variable 'maxordine' is not defined in the FROM clause"

Tags: jpa, jpql

I tried to write this query in my Java EE application:

```
public List<Fornitore> findByMaxOrdine(int maxordine) 
{
    Query query;
    query = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Fornitore b WHERE b.maxOrdini > maxordine");
    query.setParameter("maxordine", maxordine);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

When I try to run it this is the result:

```
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT b FROM Fornitore b WHERE b.maxOrdini > maxordine][46, 55] The identification variable 'maxordine' cannot be used in conjunction with the > operator.[46, 55] The identification variable 'maxordine' is not defined in the FROM clause.
```

I can not understand why it does not work.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try `SELECT b FROM Fornitore b WHERE b.maxOrdini > :maxordine`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `maxordine` is a named parameter, then your query should rather be:

```
"SELECT b FROM Fornitore b WHERE b.maxOrdini > :maxordine"
```

You can also use positional parameters, instead of named ones, if you wish. Then, the (re-factored) method would look like:

```
public List<Fornitore> findByMaxOrdine(int maxordine) {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Fornitore b WHERE b.maxOrdini > ?1")
           .setParameter(1, maxordine);
           .getResultList();
}
```